# Python function solves only last request

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Im on Google Collab i write this code and it only solves last last line and not previous ones. How i can fix it?

```
def op(a,b)->bool:
  if a==b:
    return True
  else:
    return False
print("x")
op(1,1)
op(2,2)
op(1,8)
```

What im getting is only:

```
x
False
```

And i should get:

```
x
True
True
False
```

Comment: Print the results of the calls to "op".

Comment: convert this  `op(1,1) op(2,2) op(1,8)` to `print(op(1,1)) print(op(2,2)) print(op(1,8))` or try to run each operation in different cell it will work..

Answer (score 0):

Print all of them, otherwise only the last function would be returned